# i have to get RUNTIMEPERMISSION for current Location

Tags: java, android

I use this function to give permission from the user :

```
private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode)
{
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"we have", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And I add this Code to Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And I called this in onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{    
     askForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,LOCATION);
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{

}
```

the user allows, but when I Check with if in next line, return to me Permission deny! 
i want to give the current location.
where is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle onPermissionResult for ACCESS\_FINE\_LOCATION properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610842/how-to-handle-onpermissionresult-for-access-fine-location-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check permission in onRequestPermissionsResult() it called when user click on allow or deny button

```
final String[] NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    };

    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(DialerHomeActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        //Granted

    } else {

        // ask for permission

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DialerHomeActivity.this,
                    NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS, 123);
        }

    }




@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 123:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                if ((grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))) {
                    //Permission granted
                } else {

                    if ((grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED && !ActivityCompat
                            .shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))) {

                        //Permission deny with never ask again

                    } else {
                        //Permission deny
                    }
                }
            }

    }

}
```